# Unable to add active class to a menu list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have side menubar in my page.when menu list is clicked,page will be redirected depends on the `href`.

After redirecting the page I need to add active class to the clicked `li` using url to keep the menu list opened. I have written the following code to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  pageUrl = '/employee/Home'
  $('#sidebar-left .nav li.active').removeClass("active");
  if (pageUrl) {
     $('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active");
  }
})
```

Here I have hardcoded the `url` for sample.

Now my problem is whenever I click the `list`, `active` class is added to the content of the `href` page.
i.e.. this url `href="/documents/doc_details"` page has `nav list` and each li has `forms` so `active`class is added to the full content of `href="/documents/doc_details"`.
I dont understand why am unable to add `active` class to only the clicked li?

Just a sample:  https://jsfiddle.net/tphdp1fa/ (no inner pages)

Can anyone help me?Thanks !!.

Answer (score 0):

Use `click` event for the `a` tag as below code snippets for enabling and disabling the active class.

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tphdp1fa/1/)

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  pageUrl = '/employee/Home'
  $('#sidebar-left .nav li.active').removeClass("active");
  if (pageUrl) {
    $('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active");
  }
});

$("body").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevented the default action of "a" tag for demo
  pageUrl = $(this).attr("href");//Give your own link here
  $('#sidebar-left .nav li.active').removeClass("active");
  if (pageUrl) {
    $('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
  <ul class="nav main-menu">
    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
      <a href="/employee/Home" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
      <a href="/documents/doc_details" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Documents</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
        <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Pay &amp; Benifits</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children" class="ng-scope">
          <a href="/pay/paymanagement" ng-click="tabName(child.name)" class="ng-binding">slips</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** I have prevented the default action of "a" tag using `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I can use only url here.because for each click page gets refreshed.

Comment: Did you check the above demo?

Comment: yes. but here no page refresh so its working.In my code it wont work.